# Are Rama and Krishna anywhere mentioned in sruti?

Tags: vedas, krishna, rama

Rama and Krishna are two important gods of hinduism. Do we have any references of them from Sruti? I want direct references from Vedas but excluding upanishads since I am already aware of their references in upanishads.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma It only gives upanishadic references which I am already aware of. I want direct Vedic references.

Comment: The question asks for _all_ the Vedic references.

Comment: Take a look at this interesting link: https://www.advaita-vedanta.org/articles/rig_vedic_ramayana/rig_vedic_ramayana-2.htm